# How to set calendar for notification before 10 minutes of the event?

Tags: java, android, events, calendar, notifications

I have created events. I want to set notification before 10 minutes of start time of the event.

I have seen in google calendar they have set it like this.

How can I set calendar to the time before events?

Here I am getting calendar instance and setting the calendar.

```
  public void notification(Calendar c)
{

    Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();

    int year =  cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int  month =  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int  day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int  hour =   cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int  minute =  cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, day);

        notification = c.getTime();
        notificationTime = df.format(notification);
       // notifyTime.setText(notificationTime);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(notification), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7, pendingIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}
```

Thank you..

Comment: set your alarmManager 10 minutes before the schedule time

Comment: In my app for event I am saving start date and end date. And I have put alert dialog to choose the day for event. so for setting time If i do cal.getTime() i will get the current date and time. How can I only retrieve day as mon, tue, and set the alarm for particular day and repeate it next mon?

Comment: format it using DateFormat or SimpleDateFormat class

Comment: alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis()- (10*60*1000),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7, pendingIntent);